# Ruby - Can I choose a location to put some code in a method inherited with Super?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, parent, super

I will put here an example:

```
class A

    def go(name = "girls")

        print "hello "
        print name
        puts " !"
    end
end

class B < A

    def go

        super("boys")
    end
end

A.new.go
B.new.go
```

result:

```
hello girls !
hello boys !
```

I need to do that but not with just params changing but adding some variables:

```
class A

    def go(name = "girls")

        dad_variable = "coders"

        print "hello "

        superAnchor("myAnchor") # put a "super anchor" here

        puts " !"
    end
end

class B < A

    def go

        superAnchor("myAnchor"){
            print dad_variable # do some code in relation with Daddy
            # do some other things but with the parent variables
            # interacting with the inherited environnement
        }
    end
end

A.new.go
B.new.go
```

result:

```
hello girls !
hello coders !
```

In summary I want to know if we can put anchor in the son class who inherit of the parent method and put some codes in association with the position of the anchors in the parent method and the environnement variables of the parent method ?

Is there a system to do that ?
Thank you guys :)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  You could, of course, add, delete or replace a parent class method, but you can't dynamically add, delete or modify statements in methods, whether they be in the same or a different class.  Perhaps you could edit to give a more concrete example of what you trying to accomplish.

Comment: *The environment(local) variables of the parent method* can be captured by `binding`. But `A.new` and `B.new` are just different objects.There is no connection here(except `A` is the super class of `B`, if you call it connection...). I wonder why you'd like to do such things.

Comment: Ok then I can't do what I want but that nothing because what I wanted to find it was a clean way and then the unique way is to recreate the method :) but ty All ;)

Comment: @CarySwoveland - I needed to find this kind of thing becase for each of the subClasses I create from the parentClass I do repeated things `musics << Music.new(name, quality, duration, size, adress, @query)` but Ty it's nothing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boys, I think, I find, that's the yield system

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_(instruction) (sorry for the french source)

but I am not really sure...

Comment: Yield won't give you access to private state, unless you pass it along with the yield statement (e.g. yield foo).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like instead of `superAnchor("myAnchor")` you could just have a method call that gets overridden in the subclass, no?  Perhaps the superclass could pass the `dad_variable` object into this method, which the method could use or ignore.  Also, subclasses shouldn't be able to read private state (or variables) of superclasses...

Comment: Yes I know that super is used to get the content of the inherited method and then on the submethod you can used all the parentMethod variables but here the problem is to put code in a specific position in the parent class... if this is what you are saying please put some code to explain ;) ty for your response

Comment: ho yes i understand the overriding system but to use a method you have to put some parameters for the method...

Answer (score 1):

I believe credit for this suggestion goes to Max. I'll just elaborate on the idea as I understand it.

You can insert a method call like `do_specialized_stuff` (with a better name) where the subclass behavior needs to diverge. Then, to customize the behavior in the subclass, just override the definition of `do_specialized_stuff`.

```
class A
    def go(name = "girls")

        dad_variable = "coders"

        print "hello "

        do_specialized_stuff(dad_variable)

        puts " !"
    end

    def do_specialized_stuff(dad_variable)
        # perhaps this is empty in class A or maybe it does something
    end
end

class B < A

    # no need to redefine the 'go' method

    def do_specialized_stuff(dad_variable)
        # specialized stuff is different in class B
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but when you invoke `super` `A#go` is executed on the instance of `B` and, like any other method, returns (to the instance of `B`) the last calculation made by the method.  If, for example, you put `dad_variable = "coders"` (or just `"coders"`) on the last line of `A#go`, `"coders"` will be returned:

```
class A
  def go(name = "girls")
    puts "hello from A"
    dad_variable = "coders"
  end
end

class B < A
  def go
    puts super
  end
end

A.new.go
  # hello from A
B.new.go
  #hello from A
  #coders
```

Comment: Yes I know that, the last not assignated variable is like a returned variable, but that's not I am looking for, I want to put some code in a specified position in parentMethod from the subMethod... but Ty :)